# How can I stop single pixel nodata values propagating through a tile pyramid when using gdal2tiles?

Tags: gdal, nodata, gdal2tiles, resampling

I am using gdal2tiles_parallel.py to generate a tile pyramid from a single geotiff with nodata value set. I have noticed that if I have a small hole in the original geotiff (say single pixel), then I get a single pixel hole in each higher zoom level I generate, so the hole effectively grows in geographic area as you zoom out.

I am using the `average` resampling method, and I believe the call which actually downsamples the code to generate each lower zoom level is `gdal.RegenerateOverview`; the gdalwarp documentation suggests that average resampling ignores nodata values, but I'm not sure that `RegenerateOverview` implements resampling in the same way and can't find any detailed documentation on how it works internally.

Does anyone know if `RegenerateOverview` ignores (or should ignore) nodata values, or if there is an alternative method I could substitute to handle nodata properly for resampling?